# $_GET is always empty

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

My laravel application is working well on localhost, but now having moved my application to a production server, it is no longer recognizing any $_GET variables passed through the URL. My production server is set up to allow multiple laravel installations, and I am handling the rewriting with a vhost.conf file and an .htaccess file located in the laravel root.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /international-experts/index.php/?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

vhost.conf

```
Alias /international-experts "/srv/http/international-experts/public"
<Directory /srv/http/international-experts>
  Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

What I have done to test it is with print_r($_GET) on multiple pages. Nothing. Reading up on the problem, it sounds like MultiViews might be part of the problem. I know I'm not the only one handling multiple laravel installations on the same server... has anyone else had to tackle this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Why is `Options -MultiViews` commented out?

Comment: It came commented out in the default .htaccess file that laravel provides. I tried enabling it both inside and outside of mod_rewrite. Probably just unnecessary.

Comment: Check your server logs and make sure the redirect still has the query string attached properly

Comment: What happens when you remove `IfModule` lines?

Comment: Nothing. I've removed Multiviews from the vhost, and the ifmodule from the .htaccess and I am continuing to have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /international-experts/index.php/?$1 [L]
```

you **create a new** query string with `?$1` and the default behaviour in this case is to throw away the old query string. You need to use the flag [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa), which you can remember as "query string append"

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /international-experts/index.php/?$1 [L,QSA]
```

If not enough to solve your problem, it is surely a part of it.

Comment: @AustinSlominski cool, that was the problem, then :-), you're welcome !

Answer (score 1):

i ran into a similar problem of `$_GET[]` empty. mostly because of a server issue somewhere and i had to generate my own `$GET` using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

```
//url='http://example.com/?search=john&location=london';
$get=array();
$query=mb_split("&",parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],PHP_URL_QUERY));
if(!empty($query)) foreach ($query as $qr){
    $vars=mb_split('=',$qr);
    $get[$vars[0]]=$vars[1];
}

var_dump($get['search']);
```